# Chi-square testing for constraining a parameter

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, data-fitting, chi-squared

I have an important question about the use of chi^2 test to constrain a parameter in cosmology. I appreciate your help. Please do not give this question negative rate (this question is important to me).

Assume we have a data file (`data.txt`) concluding 600 data and this data file has 3 columns, first column is redshift(z), second column is observational dL(m_obs) and third column is error(err). As we know chi^2 function is

```
 chi^2=(m_obs-m_theo)**2/err**2  #chi^2=sigma((m_obs-m_theo)**2/err**2) from 1 to N=600
```

All of thing that we must calculate is putting `z` from given data file into our function in `m_theo` for all 600 data and calculate chi^2. Now in `m_thoe` we have a free parameter(`o_m`) and we have to find its value in which the chi^2 reach its minimum value.

```
q= 1/sqrt( (1+z)**2 * (1+0.01*o_m*z) - z*(2+z)*(1-0.01*o_m) )
m_theo = 5.0 * log10( (1+z)*q ) + 43.1601
```

This question is not repetitive and is very important to every body using chi^2 specially for cosmologists and physicists.
How to find minimized chi^2 and relative `o_m`?

```
from math import *
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
min=l=a=b=chi=None
c=0   #for Sigma or summation chi^2 terms in c=c+chi for first term
def ant(z,o_m):    #0.01*o_m  is steps of o_m
   return 1/sqrt(((1+z)**2*(1+0.01*o_m*z)-z*(2+z)*(1-0.01*o_m)))
for o_m in range(24,35,1): #arbitrary range of o_m
############## opening data file containing 580 dataset
    with open('data.txt') as f: 
        for i, line in enumerate(f): #
            n= list(map(float, line.split())) #
            for i in range(1):
##############               
                q=quad(ant,0,n[1],args=(o_m,))[0]  #Integration o to z, z=n[1]
                h=5*log10((1+n[1])*(299/70)*q)+25    #function of dL
                chi=(n[2]-h)**2/n[3]**2       #chi^2 test function
                c=c+chi            #sigma from 1 to N of chi^2 and N=580
        if min is None or min>c:
            min=c
            print(c,o_m)
```

I think my code is correct but it doesn't give me a proper answer.
Thank you and I appreciate your time and your attention.

Comment: This question is off-topic on Stackoverflow, since it is not about a distinctive programming problem. However, you may want to have a a look at [scipy.optimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html) for numerical optimization. If you want to solve your problem analytically, you should consider using [maximum likelihood method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation).

Comment: @maxpowers this is exactly a problem, i have written a code but it does not give me the proper answer. thank you for your help

Comment: I attached the code, may help. thank you. Please do not give me negative rate. It is not fair my friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct answer:

```
 from math import *
 import numpy as np
 from scipy.integrate import quad
 min=l=a=b=chi=None
 c=0
 z,mo,err=np.genfromtxt('Union2.1_z_dm_err.txt',unpack=True)
 def ant(z,o_m):            #0.01*o_m  is steps of o_m
     return 1/sqrt(((1+z)**2*(1+0.01*o_m*z)-z*(2+z)*(1-0.01*o_m)))
 for o_m in range(20,40):
     c=0
     for i in range(len(z)):
         q=quad(ant,0,z[i],args=(o_m,))[0]     #Integration o to z
         h=5*log10((1+z[i])*(299000/70)*q)+25     #function of dL
         chi=(mo[i]-h)**2/err[i]**2               #chi^2 test function
        c=c+chi
        l=o_m
        print('chi^2=',c,'Om=',0.01*l,'OD=',1-0.01*l)
```